# Call the Jquery function when different buttons are clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to call a below jquery function when delete buttons in my application are clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#new').click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete user": function() {             
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
        });
        });
  });
```

How can i achieve this?
The problem is the id and class names of the buttons are different. Not able to change the id and class because it may used somewhere for different functionality.

I need to place this function in one place and i need to call wherever the delete button is used and i when the delete button in the dialog box is clicked i need to pass different delete methods.

For example: In user page i have to call deleteuser() method and in client page i have to call deleteclient() method. The method should called depending on the page.

Comment: Some buttons means which buttons?

Comment: Then give them a new classname to share amongst them.

Comment: The class name and id of buttons are used for any other functionality. I don't want to change in complete application

Comment: you can see below two different tags:                                                    <input type="submit" id="new" class="orangeBu smallBu" value="Delete User" >                                                                                                                                       <Button id="deleteInvitation" name="deleteInvitation" class="buOrange small" value="${item.invitationActivityId}"
onClick="deleteInvitationByInvitationId('${item.invitationActivityId}',this)">Delete</Button>

Comment: You can add multiple classes to button. So add simple class to all button on which you want to call this function. and then write code to call function according to class applied to button.

Comment: dont change it just add new class like this <div class="your_current_class your_new_class"> use space to separate class names

Comment: @pramodpatel Sorry, I didn't get your exact problem. You have a delete button. And now you want to handle it's click?

Answer (score 0):

change id from button element:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('button').click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete user": function() {
                deleteUser();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
            });
            });
      });
```

Comment: Then all button react to this

Comment: yes i have some other button also. they also react for this.